# Hadoop on Docker Swarm Problem with accessing DataNodes

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, docker-swarm

I am currently setting up a Hadoop Cluster on four machines. I have one namenode and four datanodes running and they communicate via a docker swarm overlay network.

Now to the problem: When trying to write to HDFS from outside the namenode delegates to the datanodes so the HDFS client tries to access those. But the addresses of the datanodes that the namenode supplies are from the interface of the docker swarm overlay network (in my case 10.0.7.0/24) and for that reason they cannot be reached from outside.

Is there a way to make the namenode return addresses of the datanodes that are reachable from outside? For example use the public IPs of the servers the datanodes are running on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with *VIP* mode in overlay network (the default) which, apparently, makes the hostname of master node point to another IP and not to the corresponing one due to overlay network behaviour with load balance ([source](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-swarm-networking-hostnames-and-service-names/90489/5)).

Reading [this section](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/#bypass-the-routing-mesh-for-a-swarm-service) in networking documentation I have solved the problem changing the `endpoint_mode` to `dnsrr` which prevents the routing mesh.

**Note that `dnsrr` mode does not support [ingress](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress) mode**, so you need to specify all the ports in host mode as [this section](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/#bypass-the-routing-mesh) indicates. Keep in mind the following caveat:

> If you expect to run multiple service tasks on each node (such as when
> you have 5 nodes but run 10 replicas), you cannot specify a static
> target port. Either allow Docker to assign a random high-numbered port
> (by leaving off the published), or ensure that only a single instance
> of the service runs on a given node, by using a global service rather
> than a replicated one, or by using placement constraints.

Thats why you need to add the `mode: global` setting too when deploy. This is my final `docker-compose.yml` file ready to run in Docker Swarm:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  # Master
  master-node:
    [...] # Extra config
    ports:
      - target: 8088
        published: 8088
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 8080
        published: 8080
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      [...] # Extra ports
    deploy:
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
      mode: global # Required by Docker Swarm to make published ports work

  # Workers (here it's not necessary to change the endpoint mode)
  worker:
    [...] # Extra config
```

Comment: by master do you mean namenode? and workers datanodes? Because namenode needs to only be replicated once, and not in all nodes. only datanodes need to be global

Comment: Yes, exactly as you say! :)

Comment: that lead me to a bit of confusion by `mode:global` in your code. If its the namenode, shouldn't that be `replicated: 1`?

Comment: just to add, the solution with `endpoint_mode: dnsrr` works for me :) the only difference is that I don't use mode global for the namenode

Comment: The `mode: global` allows you to expose some port in the host machine like the 8088 or 8080 (control panels of Hadoop and Spark). If you don't need to access that pages you can remove the global namespace and use `replicas: 1`

Comment: I can access them even with `replicas: 1`. I just add the `hostname` keyword too, and it works

Answer (score 0):

I could't solve it using the swarm overlay network so I switched to using the host network. After that, I configured Hadoop to use the public IP of namenode and resourcemanager and it worked!